# what's the most basic way to tell if a custom dimension was sent/received successfully in in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've successfully created a Custom Dimension for my property in GA. I copied the test code provided in GA and put it in my js code.  I have GA Debugger plugin installed and running. The GA js gets hit and runs in my page as expected.  The following information is output to the console:

```
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Running command: ga("set", "dimension1", "my-dimension-value")
```

No type of "Completed" message is ever written to the console. Does the message output to the console as displayed above represent a completed transaction?  Or does the lack of a "completed" message in the console mean that the transaction never completed?

Is there a simple way to view the raw custom dimension data logged to GA?  Or is this only possible through a custom report? Looks like a custom report requires at least 1 metric before adding a dimension drilldown.  If I'm only interested in the dimension drilldown info then would "Entrances" be the most basic metric I can select in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible through a custom report. However, the metrics in the report would depend on the scope of your custom dimension. The safest metric to use would probably be pageviews.

In addition, 2 good ways to debug a test like this is

1) Include test UTM paramaters in your URL and create a segment for those source/medium conditions. E.g. site.com?utm_source=test_customDimensions&utm_medium=test

2) Create a Test view, and create a include filter for traffic from only your IP address.